# python opencv won't write video using Video-writer object?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to save a OpenCV video stream using video writer object when the button is pressed but it saves only 5.5kb file.

```
def OnRecord(self, evt):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not(capture.isOpened()):
       print "Error"
    # video recorder
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')  
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter.open("output.avi", fourcc, 20, (640, 480), True)

    # record video
    while (capture.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if ret==True:
            video_writer.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        else:
            break

def OnCancel(self, evt):
    capture.release()
    video_writer.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

what's the problem?

Note - I am on Raspberry-pi.

Answer (score 0):

`video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter.open("output.avi", fourcc, 20, (640, 480),True)`

gives me error. I tried

`video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20, (640, 480), True)`

and it works.

Also make sure you `release` `capture` and `video_writer` using `capture.release()` and `video_writer.release()`.

And `cv2.imshow('Video', frame)`  wont work like this, you have to add `cv2.waitKey(1)` after it to make it work.

**EDIT:**

It maybe a problem with your device driver. Follow the instructions [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=62364) and it should work fine.

Comment: `def OnRecord(self, evt):`
   `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` 
    `if (not capture.isOpened()):`
        `print "Error"`                                                                                    I tried the above code it prints "Error" So might be a prob with my Loop. correct me if am wrong                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               I'll try yours and let you know ASAP. Thank you @shiva

Comment: This `if` statement is not in the code you posted above, can you post the exact code?

Comment: I have edited my Question, sorry for the mess. @shiva

Comment: I have been trying to install V4l2 driver as per your link but it throws an error.                                                                               The error look like this :                                                                      E: Package 'libjpeg62-dev' has no installation candidate @shiva

Comment: I have managed to install v4l2 driver as in the link provided by you but still it doesn't writes video.